# How to stop bookmarks from remembering the cursor place?

Tags: bookmarks

Bookmarks remember the file together with the place of the cursor when the file is bookmarked.  But I just want the cursor to start in the beginning of the file when visiting it through bookmarks.

Then how to stop bookmarks from remembering the cursor place?

Comment: Write a command that temporarily moves the cursor to beginning of buffer and then bookmarks. Or edit the bookmark record after it is created. Or define your own bookmarking command.

Comment: Not sure if it's even possible. maybe something like `(add-hook 'bookmark-after-jump-hook #'beginning-of-buffer)` does what you want.